# How to set location of a form

Tags: c#

What I am trying to do is make a dll that when ran will have a border-less from pop up. The form will be topmost at all times, and it will be opaque. I will also be able to click the through the form. As of right now all of that works, the problem I am having is setting the forms location. When I try to set the forms location it just doesn't move.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace pic
{
public class Class1
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern UInt32 GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, uint crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);
    public const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    public const int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;
    public const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
    public const int LWA_ALPHA = 0x2;
    public const int LWA_COLORKEY = 0x1;


    public void t()
    {

        Console.Beep(100,100);
        Form f = new Form();
        f.BackColor = Color.White;
        f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        f.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        f.TopMost = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("c:\\users\\mike\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\pic\\pic\\Grapes.png");
        f.Size = new Size(bitmap.Size.Width, bitmap.Size.Height);
        f.Location = new Point(500, 500);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Console.Beep(500,200);
        SetWindowLong(f.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
        (IntPtr)(GetWindowLong(f.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) ^ WS_EX_LAYERED ^ WS_EX_TRANSPARENT));
        // set transparency to 50% (128)
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(f.Handle, 0, 128, LWA_ALPHA);
        f.BackgroundImage = Bitmap.FromFile("c:\\users\\mike\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\pic\\pic\\Grapes.png");
        Application.Run(f);

    }

}
}
```

Comment: when you say "it moved a little" - what did it move a little in reference to? From the last run? Could it be the autoposition that windows does that "moves it a little"? for instance, if you click win+e multiple times the explorers will be stacked with offset, not on each other. Is that the moving your window does?

Comment: @Default you are right it didn't really move. It just changes position on each run.

Comment: oh, that was my next suggestion. So fiddling with the `StartPosition` values does nothing either? Setting it to `Manual` feels like it should resolve the issue.

Comment: You need to add `f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;`

Comment: generally speaking using the Location is the way to move the form. I have done this on a simple application and it works fine. out of curiosity, what are you doing on the form load event (or similar) on the Form class.

Comment: @Default thanks! works now that i set it to manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the forms [`StartPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well, since the default is (probably) `WindowsDefaultLocation`. With the default location Windows will automatically place the Form

```
f.StartPosition = Manual;
```

This would instead use the `Location` coordinates to place the Form.